# How can we solve $M^t (dM/dx) = C$?

Tags: calculus, matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

We have $M[x]$ and $C$ as $3 \times 3$ matrices.  If $M^t (dM/dx) = C$, and $C$ is a constant skew-symmetric matrix. How can we solve for $M$?

Boundary conditions: $M =$ Identity matrix at $x$ =0.

You may suggest a way to solve it in Mathematica.

Comment: Clearly the solution is $M(x)=\exp(xC)$.

Comment: Thanks. Got it.